# Binary Search Trees in php

Tags: php, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

So I'm really new to php (starting learning yesterday)
I'm having a bit of trouble with implementing a binary search tree. 
I want to be able to read in lines from a file (this I have ok) and convert them to nodes in a binary tree. 
I need the to be able to add nodes to the tree and search for a value in it, however, it's not doing anything.

Here is my code so far, can anyone see the issue?

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>

<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>


    <?php 
        echo $_SESSION[$datefull];
        $query = $_SESSION[$datefull];

        echo '</br></br>';

        readDates("dates_list.txt");
        createNodes();
        insertNodes();

    ?>

</p>

    <?php
        function readDates($file) {
            $datesList = fopen($file, "a+") or die("Unable to open file");

            $i = 0;
            $lines = array();
            while(!feof($datesList)){

                $lines[$i] = fgets($datesList);
                echo $lines[$i] . "</br>";
            }
            fclose($datesList);
        }
    ?>


<?php 
    class Node 
    {
        public $level = 1;
        public $data = NULL;
        public $left = NULL;
        public $right = NULL;

        public function __construct($data) 
        {
            $this->data = $data;
        }
    }

    class BinarySearchTree 
    {
        private $_topNode = NULL;
        private $_count = 0;
        private $_height = 1;

        /**
        * Insert a value into the tree.
        */
        public function insert($data) 
        {
            $newNode = new Node($data);

            if ( $this->_topNode === NULL ) 
            {
                $this->_topNode = &$newNode;
            } 
            else 
            {
                $current = $this->_topNode;

                    while ( $current !== NULL ) 
                    {
                        if ( $data < $current->data ) 
                        {
                            $newNode->level++;

                            if ( $current->left !== NULL ) 
                            {
                                $current = $current->left;
                            } 
                            else 
                            {
                                $current->left = $newNode;
                                break;
                            }
                        } 
                        else if ( $data > $current->data ) 
                        {
                            $newNode->level++;

                            if ( $current->right !== NULL ) 
                            {
                                $current = $current->right;
                            } 
                            else 
                            {
                                $current->right = $newNode;
                                break;
                            }
                        } 
                        else 
                        {
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }

            $this->_count++;
        }


        /**
        * Search the tree for a given value.
         */
        public function search($data) 
        {
            $current = $this->_topNode;

            while ( $current !== NULL ) 
            {
                if ( $data < $current->data ) 
                {
                    if ( $current->left !== NULL ) 
                    {
                        $current = $current->left;
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        return FALSE;
                    }
                } 
                else if ( $data > $current->data ) 
                {
                    if ( $current->right !== NULL ) 
                    {
                        $current = $current->right;
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        return FALSE;
                    }
                } 
                else 
                {
                    return $current;
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * Return the size of the tree.
         */
        public function size() 
        {
            return $this->_count;
        }
?>


    <?php
        function createNodes()
        {
            $tree = new BinarySearchTree();
            $nodes = array();
            for($j = 0; $j < count($lines); $j++)
            {
                $temp = $lines[$j];
                $nodes[$j] = new Node($temp);
            }
        }

        function insertNodes()
        {
            for($k = 0; $k < count($nodes); $k++)
            {
                $temp = $nodes[$k];
                $tree->insert($temp);
            }
        }
    ?>
</body> 


</html>
```

Comment: Firstly, how/where is `$datefull` being defined, or is that irrelevant?

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: @Fred-ii- oh sorry, $datefull is defined in another php page. eventually, I want to search the tree for this value but I haven't quite got onto it yet.

I added error_reporting(E_ALL); 
 ini_set('display_errors', 1); after session_start() but it didn't display anything

Comment: $tree & $nodes in insertNodes() function are undefined!!!

Comment: @noob I defined it in createNodes(), does it not carry over?

Comment: @AlexisCorney No they wont as they are two separate functions, How you expect variables locally defined in one function to be carried over the other? (without not even calling the other function)

Comment: $tree and $node are local variables and there scope is only confined to that method or function

Comment: @noob ah ok, sorry
I'll move the position of the definition, see if that helps

Comment: and as @Fred-ii- pointed $_SESSION[$datefull]; is wrong declaration. A session is a global array and it cannot have variables in it. It can only have key values. It should look something like $_SESSION['whatEverYouDefinedInPreviousPage'] ;

Comment: @noob, yeah I thought that, by datefull isn't really doing anything at the moment so it shouldn't affect the tree

Comment: if it isn't doing anything I suggest you to remove it. cause it will throw an error and your code execution will stop

Comment: @noob okay, I'll comment it out